# Using redis sorted sets to maintain a capped list of top users (by score)

Tags: redis

I'd like to maintain a list of top 100 users (by score) in a python project I'm doing. I feel redis `sorted sets` can be a great tool for the said purpose.

However, I don't want to maintain records for every user who ever scored. That would be a sizeable `sorted set`, and I solely want the top 100 users by aggregate score.

Remaining within the ambit of redis, is there a way to employ `sorted sets` in order to achieve this?

I know one can do `lpush` and `ltrim` in case of lists, but that's a much simpler case where no sorting by `score` is required. So how do I go about doing this?

I understand this question can be answered outside the realm of redis `sorted sets` too, but redis `sorted sets` are a great tool and as such, illustrating a sample answer using them would be great for what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean *'by aggregate score'*? Does a user's score might change? Say, at time point 1, the user's score is `5`, and at time point 2, the user gets another score of `3`. So the user's total score changes to `5 + 3 = 8`?

Comment: @for_stack: yes that's the rub. It's a changing number.

Comment: In that case, if you want to get an accurate result, you have to save scores for all users. If you are tolerant with some error, you can take @Itamar's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do that, but requires some set up in order to have the Top-100 Sorted Set managed correctly.

The algorithm is explained in https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~satishr/cs270/sp11/rough-notes/Streaming-two.pdf (see the 1st algorithm). I've implemented this a while back as a Redis module (topk - https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/topk), but it should be also doable without resorting to the modules API.

Comment: Thanks Itamar. I'm trying to figure out if there's any qualitative difference in your implementation and the shared Berkeley PDF. It seems the 1st algo in the PDF recommends decrementing all counters in the set if its cardinality overflows when there's a new candidate to be added (but leaves the candidate item unadded). Your implementation decrements all counters when the set cardinality overflows and then *always adds the candidate item*. Am I seeing it correctly?

Comment: I forgot what I did there, but IIRC it is just an optimization - there's a global counter that I increment instead of all scores. It is encoded in the zsets "first" (0 score?) element.

Comment: `Count Min Sketch` is a clever algorithm. A trade-off between memory efficiency and inaccurate result :)

Comment: @for_stack: I was under the impression Itamar was referring to 1.1 (Deterministic) and not 1.2 (Count min sketch)??

Comment: @HassanBaig I didn't check the code. But from his answer, the code should implement the 1st algorithm. I mentioned `Count Min Sketch`, only because I used it once. Sorry for the confusion I made.

Comment: CMS is also a cool thingamabob - another shameless plug: https://redislabs.com/blog/count-min-sketch-the-art-and-science-of-estimating-stuff/

Answer (score 1):

Top-K is a brand new datatype in RedisBloom.
It has a simple command set and is very lean. In some benchmarks, it was five times faster and took less than 1% of the memory than a sorted-set required.
You can learn about it [here](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisbloom/TopK_Commands/).

Redis has published a [new blog](https://redislabs.com/blog/meet-top-k-awesome-probabilistic-addition-redisbloom/) about Top-K solution.